# JNDI Initial Context & Lookup_problem for EJB 3

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0

This issue is very common. I have read some articles but can't find the problem. I want to create a simple HelloWorld program in EJB 3.0, eclipse luna, jboss 7.1.1 Final.

Here is my bean:

```
package com.tcs.HelloWorldPack;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class HelloWorld
 */
@Stateless(mappedName="HelloWorldBean")
public class HelloWorld implements HelloWorldRemote {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public HelloWorld() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void displayMsg() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");

    }

}
```

Here is my remote interface:

```
package com.tcs.HelloWorldPack;

import javax.ejb.Local;
//import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface HelloWorldRemote {

    void displayMsg();
}
```

Here is my client which is running in the same machine:

```
package com.tcs.HelloWorldClient;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.tcs.HelloWorldPack.*;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class HelloWorldClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {


        final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();
        jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "myUser");
        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "myPass");
//        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
//        jndiProperties.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

        final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        final String appName= "HeloWorldEJBEAR";
        final String moduleName= "";
        final String distinctName ="";
        final String beanName = "HeloWorld";
        final String viewClassName = "com.tcs.HelloWorldPack.HelloWorldRemote";
        HelloWorldRemote hello = (HelloWorldRemote) context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);

        hello.displayMsg();


    }

}
```

This is my jboss-ejb-client.properties file:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

remote.connection.default.username=myUser
remote.connection.default.password=myPass
```

I have put the properties file in the classpath also.But this is happening when I am trying to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:HeloWorldEJBEAR,modulename:,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@413ded77
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:584)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.displayMsg(Unknown Source)
    at com.tcs.HelloWorldClient.HelloWorldClient.main(HelloWorldClient.java:71)
Jan 08, 2015 3:34:44 PM org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ChannelAssociation$ResponseReceiver handleEnd
INFO: Channel Channel ID de8d2aa6 (outbound) of Remoting connection 44477156 to localhost/127.0.0.1:4447 can no longer process messages
```

I have also uploaded my directory structure. I am new to the EJB concept. Please help me to find where is the problem. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: have you added you ejb module into ejb client.

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you are asking. I have a ejbmodule associated with my session bean & another ejbmodule for for my client @Manoj Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module name is an empty String, but the module name can't be an empty string in the JNDI name.
Look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI)

you have to set the name of your ejb module .jar, without the .jar suffix.

`final String moduleName = "HeloWorldEJB";`

Then it should work.

Comment: But I have deployed the EJB using EAR not using JAR. That is why I have kept moduleName empty. Anyway I have changed the module name as you suggested. But still the problem is there. @user3584190

Comment: Does it work when you uncommend both jndiProperties.put and set remote://localhost:4447 instead of jnp://localhost:1099.
In AS7 you use remote:// instead of jnp://

Comment: Thank you !! :) Yes, uncommenting those two lines & changing the url did the trick. But can you explanin what is the significance of those  two lines? I am new in EJB

Comment: @SumitPal I'm also not so familiar with remote EJB invocation via jndi. On this site [docs.jboss...](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project)  they wrote:
`Those 2 properties are important for jboss-remote-naming project to be used for communicating with the AS7 server. The first property tells ... `
Hope this is helping you.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you are out to do a simple example lets keeep it simple [KISS],Most of your code is correct the catch is the client, I have simplified the client code, added my comments in client hope its self explanatory.And.... Added on EJB @javax.ejb.Stateless(name = "HelloWorldEJB") //This is portable No Vendor locked in. Alternative is mappedName [removed from your code @Stateless(mappedName="HelloWorldBean") p]which i believe is more weblogic and glassfish centric.
2. Ensure you have *client*.jar in your class path. this is the only jar you will have to add aftr you have created the EJB project in intelija or eclipse or any other ide.
3. I have deployed the EJB's in glassfish container once ear deployed successfully, run the client.
4. Apart from the below code you wont need any other configurations. This code is portable and should work on most containers however Surprises is fun do run as is and let me know .....
5. Once the below works for you  you can add other jndi properties as per your project requirement and move on.....

==============================

1. The Remote

   package com.au.ejbs;
   import javax.ejb.Remote;

   ```
   @Remote
   public interface HelloWorldI {
      String displayMessage(String message);
   }




   =================================
   2. The Impl

   package com.au.ejbs;

   import javax.ejb.Remote;

   @javax.ejb.Stateless(name = "HelloWorldEJB")
   public class HelloWorld implements HelloWorldI {
       @Override
       public String displayMessage(String message) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           return "Returning from Remote" + message;
       }
   }



   ======================================
   3. The client

   package com.au.clients;

   import com.au.ejbs.HelloWorldI;

   import javax.naming.Context;
   import javax.naming.InitialContext;
   import javax.naming.NamingException;

   public class HelloWorldT {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
           Context context = new InitialContext();
           HelloWorldI helloWorldI = (HelloWorldI)context.lookup("java:global/ejb3_2_ear_exploded/ejb/HelloWorldEJB");
           //portable syntax java:global/[ ear name]/[module name normally the jar name in my case ejb.jar within the ear, ejb3_2_ear_exploded]/name in ....javax.ejb.Stateless(name = "HelloWorldEJB")/
           System.out.println( "output " + helloWorldI.displayMessage("From Client with luv...."));
       }
   }

   ===================
   4. output
   output Returning from RemoteFrom Client with luv....
   ```